# How can I expose Ingress service on 80 and 443 to the outer world

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ingress, google-kubernetes-engine

I used google compute engine to setup a Self Managed Kubernetes, While exposing ingress service via NodePort/LoadBalancer/EnternalIP, it is using default 30000 port range, But I want to expose it on 80 and 443 to the outer world. Please suggest How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's would be better if you will use `ClusterIP` type as a service than apply `Ingress` resource on it

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#single-service-ingress